# Is it possible to use union in Tableau 10.2 to join multiple variables within the same worksheet?

Tags: tableau-api, survey

I have survey data from SurveyMonkey where 4 routes have been created through the survey manually (according to type of stakeholder). What this looks like is a large number of repeated variables e.g.

[Data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBVHi.png)

Is it possible to join these repeated variables together within Tableau? As I am essentially just appending data, the most relevant type of join seems to be a Union. However, as far as I can see, a Union would only work if each survey route was in a separate worksheet.

Just interested to see whether there's a way to do this, without manually separating the survey routes before connecting to them in Tableau.

Thanks

Comment: if you are using Tableau to visualize survey data, the first step is to read the blog entries on http://www.datarevelations.com The author, Steve Wexler, has been using Tableau with survey data for several years and has published alot of good advice

Comment: Thanks this is a really helpful resource